# Как поворачивать объект в сторону другого на определенный угол

Tags: c#, unity3d, rotation

> Как  поворачивать объект  в сторону другого на определенный угол.

Не 2D, `Quaternion.Lerp` не то, все таки это интерполяция.

Что тут еще можно добавить не знаю.

Comment: Векторное произведение, почитайте https://habrahabr.ru/post/131931/

Comment: Я не понимаю как это может мне помочь.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Узнать надо сначала куда поворачиваем -

```
  Vector3 newDir = Vector3.RotateTowards(transform.forward, (target.transform.position-transform.position), radian_angle, 0.0F);
```

и повернуть

```
 transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(newDir);
```

radian_angle - угол поворота в радианах

Comment: Спасибо, вроде то что нужно!) Мне не хватало `Vector3.RotateTowards`